# QUERY RESOLUTION

Tags: mysql, database

Having this database model:

```
Movie(id_movie, title, id_director(FK), year, duration, country, facebook_likes, imbued_score, gross, budget)

Actor_Movie(id_actor(FK),id_movie(FK))

Person(id_person, name, facebook_likes)

Actor(id_actor(FK))

Director(id_director(FK))

Genre(id_genre,description)

Genre_Movie(id_genre(FK),id_movie(FK))

Producer(id_producer, name, country)

Producer_Movie(id_producer(FK), id_movie(FK))

Language(id_language,language)

Language_Movie(id_language(FK), id_movie(FK))
```

I want to do the following query but I don't know how to add the 'where all the actors in it start with the letter A ' part.

Select the IMDB title and note from those movies where all the actors in it start with the letter A and have raised more than $ 60 million (gross), ordered by IMDB score.

This is what I have until now:

```
select m.title
     , m.imdb_score
  from movie as m
     , actor as a
     , actor_movie as am
     , person as p
 where p.id_person = a.id_actor 
   and a.id_actor = am.id_actor 
   and am.id_movie = m.id_movie 
 group 
    by m.title
     , m.imdb_score
having m.imdb_score > 6.0 
 order 
    by m.imdb_score DESC;
```

Comment: You can also think of it as `where none of the actors don't start with 'a'`

Answer (score 0):

"Actor name started with the letter A" is : `a.name LIKE 'A%'`.
"All the actors in movie start with the letter A" is a bit tricky. Let me start from afar.

You query look prety good but I have to make some minor notes:

- It is common to move relations into JOIN clauses and leave WHERE for all other conditions;
- HAVING clause is used for after-group-by condition which is NOT applicable in WHERE clause. Something like that : `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`. In your case, you can easily move imdb_score inside WHERE.

One of the possible implementation is:

```sql
SELECT
    m.title,
    m.imdb_score 
FROM movie AS m 
JOIN actor_movie AS am ON am.id_movie = m.id_movie 
JOIN actor AS a ON a.id_actor = am.id_actor 
JOIN person AS p ON p.id_person = a.id_actor
WHERE m.imdb_score > 6.0 
AND m.gross > 60000000
GROUP BY
    m.title,
    m.imdb_score 
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(a.name LIKE 'A%')
ORDER BY m.imdb_score DESC
```

Logical expression inside SUM() gives 1 (true) or 0 (false), so this way we can count amount of actors satisfied some condition, while COUNT(*) is unconditional count. We can compare them to get the trick.

Comment: I have the answer of the query and it doesn't match with the solution of the query you  posted...

Comment: @GASNOBLE it is okay if you'll post your own solution and mark it as an answer.
By the way, it can be more than one implementation of the same task in SQL ;)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(movie_id INT NOT NULL, actor VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(movie_id,actor));

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1,'alan'),(1,'angela'),(1,'albert'),(1,'annie');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (2,'alan'),(2,'alice'),(2,'arnold'),(2,'barbara');

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----------+---------+
| movie_id | actor   |
+----------+---------+
|        1 | alan    |
|        1 | albert  |
|        1 | angela  |
|        1 | annie   |
|        2 | alan    |
|        2 | alice   |
|        2 | arnold  |
|        2 | barbara |
+----------+---------+

SELECT DISTINCT a.movie_id  
           FROM my_table a 
           LEFT 
           JOIN my_table b   
             ON b.movie_id = a.movie_id 
            AND b.actor NOT LIKE 'a%' 
           WHERE b.movie_id IS NULL;
+----------+
| movie_id |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
```